# How to fix major lag in NSTimers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstimer

In a fairly simple application that I am making, I use many NSTimers, one which runs at a rate of .01 seconds that I use to change the position of multiple images.  This causes major lag.  How can I fix this?  Please explain in detail, as I am fairly new to app dev.

Comment: If you're doing something every 10 ms then it had better take much less than 10 ms to execute, perhaps 1 ms.

Comment: Also, given that the screen refreshes between 15 and 30 ms, there's little point in updating a view more often than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the NSTimer Docs (emphasis: mine):

> A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the
>   run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able
>   to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various
>   input sources a typical run loop manages, the effective resolution of
>   the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of **50-100 
>   milliseconds**. If a timer’s firing time occurs during a long callout or
>   while the run loop is in a mode that is not monitoring the timer, the
>   timer does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer.
>   Therefore, the actual time at which the timer fires potentially can be
>   a significant period of time after the scheduled firing time.

If you want to work at the display frequency, see `CADisplayLink`.

However, you should first understand where you program spends its time now to understand what makes it slow (profiler).